# Converting JSON to .csv

Tags: json, csv

I've found some data that someone is downloading into a JSON file (I think! - I'm a newb!). The file contains data on nearly 600 football players.

Here's the file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/llimllib/fantasypl_stats/f944410c21f90e7c5897cd60ecca5dc72b5ab619/data/players.1426687570.json

Is there a way I can grab some of the data and convert it to .csv? Specifically the 'Fixture History'?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: maybe it helps you http://www.convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm

Comment: do you want to convert it in code? if so, what languages are you using?

Comment: Thanks for responding, i'm new to this. I want to extrapolate some of the data into a .csv so I can play with the data in a table, specifically 'fixture history'. I wonder if you could take a look and give me some pointers on how to do this?

Comment: JSON is a more detailed data format than CSV - it allows for more complex data structures. Inevitably if you do this, you 'lose detail'.  So an example of what you've in mind for output would be useful. Each player has multiple fixtures - would you be thinking a column for each, or a row for each fixture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python has some good libraries for doing this. If you copy the following code into a file and save it as *fix_hist.py* or something, then save your JSON file as *file.json* in the same directory, it will create a csv file with the fixture histories each saved as a row. Just run `python fix_hist.py` in your command prompt (or terminal for mac):

```
import csv
import json

json_data = open("file.json")
data = json.load(json_data)

f = csv.writer(open("fix_hists.csv","wb+"))

for i in data:
    fh = data[i]["fixture_history"]
    array = fh["all"]
    for j in array:
        f.writerow(j)
```

`json_data.close()`

To add additional data to the fixture history, you can add insert statements before writing the rows:

```
import csv
import json

json_data = open("file.json")
data = json.load(json_data)

f = csv.writer(open("fix_hists.csv","wb+"))

arr = []

for i in data:
    fh = data[i]["fixture_history"]
    array = fh["all"]
    for j in array:

        try:
            j.insert(0,str(data[i]["first_name"]))
        except:
            j.insert(0,'error')

        try:
            j.insert(1,data[i]["web_name"])
        except:
            j.insert(1,'error')

        try:
            f.writerow(j)
        except:
            f.writerow(['error','error'])

json_data.close()
```

With `insert()`, just indicate the position in the row you want the data point to occupy as the first argument.

Comment: Hi Brennan, that's fantastic, thanks for that. How would I go about adding 'first name', 'last name' etc. to this table using the code above? How would I adapt the code above to grab First Name, last name, fixtures etc.?

Comment: hey @Johnliquid, I just edited the answer to include a way to insert additional data. let me know if that helps.
also, if my solution worked for you, please accept my answer so i can get points for it :)

Comment: Hi Brennan, thanks for your response. I just tried your update as before, the following error shows up in command prompt: 

File "fix_hist.py", line 17, in <module>
f.writerow<j>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'xe1' in position 4: 
ordinal not in range<128>

Comment: i got that same error when i ran the code, but the csv file was still created. let me look at writing a handler for that...

Comment: Thank Brennan, I checked the .csv and it had only partially downloaded 29 players data, not starting from the first player (there are nearly 600 players in the league). Really appreciate your assistance!

Comment: okay, if you look at the last edited answer, i added some error handlers. if the value of the cell creates encoding problems, it is replaced with the word 'error'. if you want, you can replace 'error' with empty space (" ") or something if you want.

ordering a JSON in its original order is not default behavior for `json_load()`

if that is an issue, you could include the number as the first argument, then use Excel to order the rows based on that

Comment: Thanks so much Brennan, really appreciate your efforts. Quite a lot of players are missing (showing up as errors), I think this is because their names include accents or other characters that don't appear in English names. Is there a way of handling these so they appear? Also, with ordering as per the original JSON, where would include the number in the first argument? - Thanks again, you've been awesome so far

Comment: yeah, there are definitely things you can do to handle the errors in a more refined way. you could write a function to search through the script of error producing text, and replace specific characters, but that is a longer solution. i can plug away at that later when i'm done at work, but it is going to take more time, and really probably not appropriate to do on this format. i'm happy to help later if you give me some way to contact you outside of SO

Comment: Hey Brennan, Thanks so much, we can keep in touch through email mr.j.w.evans@gmail.com - really appreciate it!

Comment: okay, i copied that into an email draft if you want to delete it. i'll work on that later tonight and contact you tonight or tomorrow

Comment: Hello Brenan .. I have a 2.7 GB JSON file.. which i downloaded from Yelp. I am trying to convert to CSV. What Python library or what version Python, I need to install on my Windows 10 OS ? Please help me..

Comment: @goofyui, [python 2.7](https://www.python.org/downloads/) has more documentation than python 3.5, but if you're planning on using python for anything other than just this one solution, you should just download [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads#windows), in my opinion, because it comes with a ton of awesome packages pre-installed that are super useful

Comment: Thank you Brennan.. I need only for this project. Does anaconda has more help documentation. I wish to get the data in couple of days.

Comment: @goofyui look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) for JSON parsing in Python

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

If the file `filter.jq` contains

```
  .[]
| {first_name, second_name, all:.fixture_history.all[]}
| [.first_name, .second_name, .all[]]
| @csv
```

and `data.json` contains the sample data then the command

```
jq -M -r -f filter.jq data.json
```

will produce the output (note only 10 rows shown here)

```
"Wojciech","Szczesny","16 Aug 17:30",1,"CRY(H) 2-1",90,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,13,7,0,55,2
"Wojciech","Szczesny","23 Aug 17:30",2,"EVE(A) 2-2",90,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,9,-9306,55,1
"Wojciech","Szczesny","31 Aug 16:00",3,"LEI(A) 1-1",90,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,2,0,7,15,-20971,55,1
"Wojciech","Szczesny","13 Sep 12:45",4,"MCI(H) 2-2",90,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,12,17,-39686,55,3
"Wojciech","Szczesny","20 Sep 15:00",5,"AVL(A) 3-0",90,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,14,22,-15931,55,6
"Wojciech","Szczesny","27 Sep 17:30",6,"TOT(H) 1-1",90,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,10,13,-5389,55,3
"Wojciech","Szczesny","05 Oct 14:05",7,"CHE(A) 0-2",90,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,3,9,-8654,55,1
"Wojciech","Szczesny","18 Oct 15:00",8,"HUL(H) 2-2",90,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,7,9,-824,54,1
"Wojciech","Szczesny","25 Oct 15:00",9,"SUN(A) 2-0",90,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,16,22,-11582,54,7
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON is a more detailed data format than CSV - it allows for more complex data structures. Inevitably if you do this, you 'lose detail'.

If you want to fetch it automatically - that's doable, but I've skipped it because 'doing' `https` URLs is slightly more complicated.

So assuming you've downloaded your file, here's a possible solution in Perl (You've already got one for Python - both are very powerful scripting languages, but can pretty much cover the same ground - so it's as much a matter of taste as to which you use).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;

my $file = 'players.json';

open( my $input, "<", $file ) or die $!;

my $json_data = decode_json(
    do { local $/; <$input> }
);
foreach my $player_id ( keys %{$json_data} ) {
    foreach my $fixture (
        @{ $json_data->{$player_id}->{fixture_history}->{all} } )
    {
        print join( ",",
            $player_id, $json_data->{$player_id}->{web_name},
            @{$fixture}, "\n", );
    }

}
```

Hopefully you can see what's going on here - you load the file `$input`, and `decode_json` to create a data structure.

This data structure is a nested `hash` (perl's term for the type of data structure). `hash`es are key-value pairs.

So we extract the `keys` from this hash - which is the ID number right at the beginning of each entry.

Then we loop through each of them - extracting the the `fixture_history` array. And for each element in that array, we print the player ID, their `web_name` and then the data from `fixture_history`.

This gives output like:

```
1,Szczesny,10 Feb 19:45,25,LEI(H) 2-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-2413,52,0,
1,Szczesny,21 Feb 15:00,26,CRY(A) 2-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-2805,52,0,
1,Szczesny,01 Mar 14:05,27,EVE(H) 2-0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1862,52,0,
1,Szczesny,04 Mar 19:45,28,QPR(A) 2-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1248,52,0,
1,Szczesny,14 Mar 15:00,29,WHU(H) 3-0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1897,52,0,
```

Does this make sense?

Comment: Hi Sobrique, tahnsk very much for your response, really appreciated. However, I haven't managed to save the JSON file yet! How would i go about doing that in Perl? Once I have managed that, then i can have a go at your method above! Thanks :)

Comment: Open it in a browser, 'save-as' would be the easiest by far. Otherwise you're looking at fetching some `https` data, using `LWP::UserAgent`. I tried a sample, and it didn't work so  haven't posted it :)

Comment: Hi Sobrique, Thanks again :) I managed to download the JSON file :) I'm using ipython, and copied your code above. I put the directory where the JSON file is in the 'players.json' part of your code above, which i assume is correct. However, I received the following error in ipython: File "<ipython-input-3-20a1e3ece873>", line 3
    use strict;
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax