# Ways to convert JSON to CSV?

Tags: json, csv

Is there any free online tool or way to convert JSON to CSV file up to 70MB. I tried a few software tools, which are allowing me to convert only up to 1 MB. I have a JSON file which is up to 70MB. Please suggest some way to convert it to CSV?

Comment: Are you only looking for off-shelf tools? If you don't mind writing some code, there are many libraries to do this, and the work can be done with no more than 100 lines of code I believe.

Comment: Yes. I was looking for something without writing code. My main job to read csv files from spark scala. So, I need some quick way to convert JSON to CSV.

Comment: I found https://json-csv.com/ which converts only upto 1 MB for free.

Answer (score 17):

If you have Python and Pandas installed. You can simply use pandas to export the json file to csv.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_json("yourfile.json").to_csv("output.csv")
```

if you don't have Pandas installed, you can install it using the following command.

```
$ pip install pandas
```

Comment: Thanks. is there any way to do it in spark and scala?

Comment: you don't have to it in Spark, because the file is pretty small. You can convert it this way first and then load it as csv into spark

Comment: I tried above method. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json.py", line 281, in read_json
    date_unit).parse()
  File "C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json.py", line 349, in parse
    self._parse_no_numpy()

ValueError: Expected object or value

Comment: Each line is big. Jan 20 00:00:00 -0800 2014, {"cl":"js","ua":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.77 Safari/537.36","ip":"76.4.253.137","cc":"US","rg":"NV","ct":"North Las Vegas","pc":"89084","mc":839,"bf":"402d6c3bdd18e5b5f6541a98a01ecc47d698420d","vst":"0e1c96ff-1f4a-4279-bfdc-ba3fe51c2a4e","lt":"Sun Jan 19 23:59:59 -0800 2014","hk":["memba","alyson stoner","memba them","member them","member them 80s","missy elliotts","www.tmzmembathem","80s memba then","missy elliott","mini"]}, {"v":"1.1",

Comment: There is a problem with the JSON file. The portion you provided looks ok and works on my machine. Try to validate the json file. I would use `# cat file | jq .` on unix to check

Comment: So you mean I need to remove date but the file is too big and date is present in each line. Any options to format json properly?

Answer (score 1):

The [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) tool can probably do what you need.

There is an online version at https://jqplay.org/ as well.  I am uncertain as to the limit of the online version but I've used it before with about 8 MiB of [data on nearly 600 football players](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/llimllib/fantasypl_stats/f944410c21f90e7c5897cd60ecca5dc72b5ab619/data/players.1426687570.json) in the answer to this question

- [Converting JSON to .csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29131111/converting-json-to-csv/45993961#45993961)

Answer (score 0):

We used [jsontoexcel](http://jsontoexcel.com) to convert our json data to CSV. I think it has a certain limit on the file upload size though.