# How to add title row to using writer and unicodecsv

Tags: python, json

I have the following JSON file - test.json (names, keys and addresses changed for security reasons)

```
   [  
   {  
      "accountMode":"Live",
      "acquirer":"TEST",
      "acquirerConstraints":{  
         "cardTypes":[  
            "MASTERCARD",
            "MAESTRO",
            "VISA"
         ],
         "cvcRegexp":"^[0-9]{3}$",
         "cvcRequired":true,
         "maxAmount":500000,
         "minAmount":50
      },
      "acquirerDetails":{  
         "TEST":"Studio",
         "ERROR_LIST":[  

         ],
         "MERCHANT_CODE":"218331",
         "VALID":true,
         "_mId":"T712484",
         "_status":"INPROCESS",
         "email":"test7@gmail.com",
         "name":"Studio",
         "valid":true
      },
      "acquirerValidations":null,
      "allowedCurrencies":[  
         "EUR",
         "USD",
         "GBP"
      ],
      "apiKeyPairs":[  
         {  
            "accountMode":"Live",
            "label":"Virtual Terminal",
            "publishableKey":"niunibiubniunijknkjknj",
            "source":"VIRTUAL_TERMINAL"
         },
         {  
            "accountMode":"Live",
            "label":"Default",
            "publishableKey":"iiuhiuhiu",
            "source":"ECOMMERCE"
         }
      ],
      "appLogoUrl":null,
      "applicationId":"541d75e0-7db8b343a31f",
      "authorizationCode":"",
      "closedDate":null,
      "closureReason":null,
      "declineAvsAddressFailure":false,
      "declineAvsZipFailure":false,
      "declineCvcFailure":false,
      "defaultCurrency":"EUR",
      "descriptor":null,
      "email":"test1@gmail.com",
      "id":"ddddeff",
      "invitationCode":null,
      "locale":"en_IE",
      "merchantApplication":{  
         "accountNumber":null,
         "acquirer":"TEST",
         "annualAmount":null,
         "annualVolume":null,
         "applicationType":"APPROVAL",
         "bankName":"UNKNOWN",
         "brand":null,
         "businessAddress":"54 My St, 1",
         "businessAddress2":null,
         "businessCity":"Abbey",
         "businessCountry":"IRL",
         "businessPhone":null,
         "businessState":"DUBLIN",
         "businessZip":null,
         "data":null,
         "email":"test@gmail.com",
         "escalationPhone":null,
         "fax":null,
         "legalName":"UAB \"Studio\"",
         "maxTransactionAmount":null,
         "mccCode":"5712",
         "merchantPromotionCode":null,
         "mobile":null,
         "monthlyAmount":null,
         "monthlyVolume":null,
         "ownerFirstName":"tlana",
         "ownerLastName":"nava",
         "phone":"37647",
         "GuideAccepted":null,
         "privacyAccepted":true,
         "privacyVersion":"1a",
         "referenceId":"9104d65i08d071",
         "routingNumber":null,
         "singleTransactionAmount":null,
         "statementName":"UAB \"Studio\"",
         "taxId":null,
         "termsAccepted":true,
         "termsVersion":"1a",
         "url":"http://www.design.lt"
      },
      "merchantId":"12484",
      "merchantPromotionCode":null,
      "mposEnabled":true,
      "name":"Studio",
      "netonfiguration":null,
      "onboardedDate":1505513232485,
      "onboardingMethod":null,
      "onboardingStatus":"INPROCESS",
      "partner":null,
      "saqCompliant":false,
      "saqExpires":null,
      "settings":[  
         {  
            "key":"MERCHANT_DETAILS",
            "value":"{\"zip\":\"Wicklow\",\"phone\":\"342647\",\"email\":\"suppoor@outlook.com\",\"address\":\"Bck 6\",\"state\":\"Ireland\",\"addressLine2\":\"Unit 8, Bl Par\",\"city\":\"Wicklow\"}"
         },
         {  
            "key":"VAT_NUMBER",
            "value":"/evzaqen/"
         }
      ],
      "timezone":"Europe/Dublin",
      "tinStatus":null
   },
   {  
      "accountMode":"Live",
      "acquirer":"TEST",
      "acquirerConstraints":{  
         "cardTypes":[  
            "MASTERCARD",
            "MAESTRO",
            "VISA"
         ],
         "cvcRegexp":"^[0-9]{3}$",
         "cvcRequired":true,
         "maxAmount":500000,
         "minAmount":50
      },
      "acquirerDetails":{  
         "TEST":"test",
         "ERROR_LIST":[  

         ],
         "MERCHANT_CODE":"594920",
         "MID_ASSIGNED":true,
         "VALID":true,
         "_mId":"103558",
         "_status":"APPROVED",
         "acquiringMid":"1036598",
         "descriptor":"test 8885551212",
         "email":"test@gmail.com",
         "gatewayMid":"SIMP337",
         "id":"SIMP337",
         "level4Mid":"76576576",
         "name":"test",
         "status":"APPROVED",
         "transactionCurrency":"USD;EUR;GBP",
         "valid":true,
         "paymentGatewayKey":"ytfytfytfyt"
      },
      "acquirerValidations":null,
      "allowedCurrencies":[  
         "EUR",
         "USD",
         "GBP"
      ],
      "apiKeyPairs":[  

      ],
      "appLogoUrl":null,
      "applicationId":"949bdde5-07-d8d58f4c3d01",
      "authorizationCode":"",
      "closedDate":null,
      "closureReason":null,
      "declineAvsAddressFailure":false,
      "declineAvsZipFailure":false,
      "declineCvcFailure":false,
      "defaultCurrency":"EUR",
      "descriptor":"test85551212",
      "email":"test@gmail.com",
      "id":"9f3a7d7",
      "invitationCode":null,
      "locale":"en_US",
      "merchantApplication":{  
         "accountNumber":null,
         "acquirer":"TEST",
         "annualAmount":null,
         "annualVolume":null,
         "applicationType":"APPROVAL",
         "bankName":"UNKNOWN",
         "brand":null,
         "businessAddress":"123 test",
         "businessAddress2":null,
         "businessCity":"Atlanta",
         "businessCountry":"IRL",
         "businessPhone":null,
         "businessState":"CARLOW",
         "businessZip":null,
         "data":null,
         "email":"test@gmail.com",
         "escalationPhone":null,
         "fax":null,
         "legalName":"stest",
         "maxTransactionAmount":null,
         "mccCode":"521",
         "merchantPromotionCode":null,
         "mobile":null,
         "monthlyAmount":null,
         "monthlyVolume":null,
         "ownerFirstName":"moto",
         "ownerLastName":"test",
         "phone":"3141212",
         "GuideAccepted":null,
         "privacyAccepted":true,
         "privacyVersion":"1a",
         "referenceId":"2920",
         "routingNumber":null,
         "singleTransactionAmount":null,
         "statementName":"test",
         "taxId":null,
         "termsAccepted":true,
         "termsVersion":"1a",
         "url":null
      },
      "merchantId":"1036558",
      "merchantPromotionCode":null,
      "mposEnabled":true,
      "name":"test",
      "netonfiguration":null,
      "onboardedDate":1456846054925,
      "onboardingMethod":null,
      "onboardingStatus":"CLOSED",
      "partner":null,
      "saqCompliant":false,
      "saqExpires":null,
      "settings":[  

      ],
      "timezone":"Europe/Dublin",
      "tinStatus":"InCompliance"
   }
]
```

I want to process this file and take some of the information and populate a CSV file with it. To do this I am using the following:

```
import unicodecsv
import json

json_data = open("test.json")
data = json.load(json_data)

f = unicodecsv.writer(open("results.csv","wb+"))
for entry in data:
    if "merchantApplication" in entry:
        ma = entry["merchantApplication"]
        if "email" in ma:
            f.writerow([ma["ownerFirstName"],ma["ownerLastName"],ma["email"],ma["legalName"],ma["businessAddress"],ma["businessAddress2"],ma["businessCity"],ma["businessCountry"],ma["businessState"],ma["businessZip"],ma["phone"],ma["mobile"]])

json_data.close()
```

This Works fine but does not print the headers above the columns. How do I add in the headers? I am using Python 2.7.10

Comment: Could you provide us your python version?

Comment: Python 2.7.10 - added above

Comment: How does the question relates to the title ???

Comment: In your previous question, the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46685210/3545273) suggested to test for the presence of email key to *protect* the script against incorrect data. You have just copied the script and added more fields without even wondering about the consequences... IMHO you should either test for presence of every key of none.

Comment: @sergeBallesta I understand this, and would do that in any other scenario, but in this case, the email is the username for the account, so there will be no entry without an email.

Comment: @Johnnerz My remark was the opposite: if the email is present but not the businessAddress2, the script will fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I add in the headers?

Well quite simply by calling `f.writerow((<your>,<headers>,<here>))` before your `for` loop.

Comment: Tried      f.writerow("Owner First Name","Owner Last Name","Email","Legal Name","Business Address","Business City","Business Country","Business State","Business Zip","phone")        And I got the following:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "merch_dets.py", line 9, in <module>
    writer.writerow("Owner First Name","Owner Last Name","Email","Legal Name","Business Address","Business City","Business Country","Business State","Business Zip","phone")
NameError: name 'writer' is not defined

Comment: of course if your writer is named `f` you have to  use `f` instead

Comment: oh and writerow takes a tuple or list (edited my answer)